# Creating and installing a Plugin for mobile Safari on ios4 devices

Tags: iphone, plugins, installation, safari, mobile-safari

I have created a simple web plug-in to write data to file system. This works as expected on a mac Safari. Here i have to manually place the plug-in on to the /Library/Internet Plug-Ins folder. My question is there a way to find if the plug-in is not present through JavaScript and if it is not then download and install the same. I also would like to know if the same can be done on mobile Safari running on ios4 devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you can not load Plugins of any kind in Safari on the iOS device. This is the main reason Flash does not exist on iOS.

On the Mac you can do that. But you need to create the plugin in C++ and for each platform independently.

If you code the plugin correctly, it should be possible to "detect" it using JavaScript. I highly doubt you can download it automatically, though. This would pose a very large security hole for every user.